# Как вызвать два метода параллельно с помощью joblib

Tags: python

Есть flask-приложение, в котором я хочу распараллелить процес распознавания сервисами. Думал сперва использововать `Queue` и `Process`, но его не получается использовать во flask, так оно требует директиву `__main__`

```
amazonstatus, idamazon = recAmazon(photo)
microsoftstatus, idmicrosoft = recMicrosoft(photo)
```